# Getting FileNotFoundException when deploying war using Maven Jetty plugin

Tags: maven-2, maven, jetty, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm using Maven 3.0.3 with the Jetty plugin. I'm getting the error below:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml

which I don't understand, because the file is present at `target/mywar/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`. I call this file in my `web.xml`:

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.4">
    <display-name>/jx-production-1.0-SNAPSHOT</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>Any ideas what I'm missing? Here is my Jetty plugin definition in my pom.xml …
    <profile>
        <id>jetty</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>7.2.2.v20101205</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <webAppConfig>
                            <contextPath>/all-new-jx</contextPath>
                            <descriptor>target/jx-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/web.xml</descriptor>
                        </webAppConfig>
                        <jettyConfig>config/jetty7/jetty.xml</jettyConfig>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <contextHandlers>
                            <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
                                <contextPath>/all-new-jx-web</contextPath>
                                <resourceBase>${project.basedir}/target/web</resourceBase>
                                <handler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler" />
                            </contextHandler>
                        </contextHandlers>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jetty-rewrite</artifactId>
                            <version>7.2.2.v20101205</version>
                            <type>jar</type>
                            <scope>runtime</scope>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Here's the long, nasty error I'm getting:

> 2011-08-04 14:08:56.677:WARN::Failed startup of context
>   o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/all-new-jx,file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/NissanUSA2/Technology/nna/mycousa/jx/src/main/webapp/},file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/NissanUSA2/Technology/nna/mycousa/jx/src/main/webapp/
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:641)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:228)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1181)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:584)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:496)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:226)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:164)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:226)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:93)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:93)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:243)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
>       Caused by: 
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:641)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:228)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1181)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:584)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:496)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:226)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:164)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:226)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:93)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:93)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:243)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're using the run goal--i.e. `mvn jetty:run`? That runs a webapp "in place", meaning it looks for classes in `target/classes` or in your project dependencies, and it loads web resources from `src/main/webapp` (assuming default directory layout). It won't find anything in `target/mywar/...`. You could use one of the other [jetty plugin goals](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin), but I'd recommend just moving your applicationContext.xml into the classpath and using `classpath:/applicationContext.xml` as your `contextConfigLocation`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using goal jetty:run and copying the necessary resources to src/main/webapp worked, so much thanks for your explanation.

Comment: jetty plugin goals link is no longer valid since codehaus move